# CentOS 6.5 + Apache Virtual Host

Tags: apache, dns, centos, virtualhost

I have installed CentOS 6.5 on my VPS (IP 149.210.167.9). Eventually I want to serve multiple domains, but for now I only want to handle 1 domain in particular: aforismo.eu. When you surf to the IP directly it shows me an Apache test page, so that works. When I ping aforismo.eu it shows me the correct IP, so I think the DNS is setup correctly. If I'm missing something trivial, please teach me :)

What I did so far to handle this domain:

---

**I)**  I've created /etc/httpd/conf.d/site-aforismo.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
    ServerAdmin    webmaster@aforismo.eu 
    DocumentRoot   /var/www/aforismo.eu/public/ 
    ServerName     aforismo.eu
    ServerAlias    *.aforismo.eu 
    ErrorLog       logs/aforismo.error_log 
    CustomLog      logs/aforismo.access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

**II)** Modified a few bits in /etc/http/conf/httpd.conf:

```
Include conf.d/*.conf

NameVirtualHost *:80
```

**III)** Afterwards I've restarted apache

```
service httpd restart
```

**IV)** Checking httpd -S results in:

```
wildcard NameVirtualHosts and _default_ servers:
_default_:443  vps.vanoosten.me (/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:74)
*:80           is a NameVirtualHost
     default server aforismo.eu (/etc/httpd/conf.d/site-aforismo.conf:1)
     port 80 namevhost aforismo.eu (/etc/httpd/conf.d/site-aforismo.conf:1)
       wild alias *.aforismo.eu Syntax OK
```

---

But ... surfing to http://www.aforismo.eu (or http://aforismo.eu) does not work. Since it's not my everyday business, I'd sure miss something quite trivial, but I can't find out what it is. Can you help me a bit further? Much appreciated.

Comment: Does it work when you hit it from that machine (`http://localhost`)?

Comment: Are you sure you can ping it, I surely cannot. Have you setup the DNS at the nameserver properly. You can check you info here: http://whois.domaintools.com/aforismo.eu

Comment: Isn't this question off-topic on Stack Overflow?

Comment: The domain nameserver does not assign IPs to it. `dig aforismo.eu ANY` does not return any A record IPs. So the problem is probably somewhere else, not in the Apache Docs.

Comment: Thank you all for your feedback; @NicolaMusatti I'm sorry if this is an off-topic question, but I'm not sure what would be the correct location for it? I'll dig into the DNS of the domain. I probably made a mistake there. Again thanks for all your advice; appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:** As you guys suggested, it turns out to be a DNS issue. I thought I had created an A record to the given IP. But ... in the interface of my DNS provider I had to use the @-character for the domain itself instead of to really write it down. So what I really created was an A-record for aforismo.eu.aforismo.eu. Fixed (and next time I promise to read the manual :P)

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add [Listen *:80](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mpm_common.html#listen).

You may also need to add [UseCanonicalName off](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#usecanonicalname) under `<VirtualHost *:80>`.

**Edit:**

Unless it's meant to be internal only, there is something wrong with your DNS.  I can hit the IP but aforismo.eu doesn't resolve to anything.

Comment: Just checked `/etc/http/conf/httpd.conf`.  Both `Listen 80` is enabled and `UseCanonicalName off` is mentioned. What exactly do you mean with _under `<VirtualHost *:80>`_? Should it be within or added below the `<VirtualHost *:80>` line?

Comment: Yes, below, but if you have them both already it may not matter.

Comment: Both available and indeed `UseCanonicalName off` is placed below `Include conf.d/*.conf`.  

It's not meant for internal use. Could you give me some directions I could dive into to fix the DNS issue? I have an A-record pointing to IP 149.210.167.9. Do I need _something_ on my VPS also to handle with domains? Sorry if this is a n00b question :P

Comment: You'll need to contact your DNS provider. There's not much you can do directly.

Comment: Thanks for your input; since all other suggestions point in the same direction; I'd like to reward my points to you.